# Variable fields woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For my webshop I am looking for a pluging or like a way to have checkout form that is not always the same.

Lets say I have 2 products, product 1 and product 2.

For product 1 I want three fields : name , last name , age.
But when people choose product 2, I want 3 different fields.

So the form has to be dynamic depending on which product you order.

How do I achieve this.

Comment: I've achieved building dynamic forms with this plugin: https://www.gravityforms.com/

Comment: Thanks for this could be handy in the future, but im looking for a solution with woocommerce since I am working with products. @RandallValenciano

Comment: @Kevin.a This can be done very easily… what are the exact fields you need to be enabled/disabled for each product?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i don't know the exact fields yet, could be anything. I'm more interested in the technique :)

Comment: So try to imagine to a real fake example that can match your technique needs **updating your question and adding the necessary details**…